# Wicket-select2 dropdown is not update after provide new modelobject

Tags: java, wicket, jquery-select2, wicketstuff

I have wicket-select2 dropdown for country.

```
Select2Choice<Country> country = new Select2Choice<Country>("country", new PropertyModel<Country>(params, "selectedCountry"),new CountriesProvider(params));
```

adding new country using popupPanel after click on add country button and below is functionality.

```
Country addCountry = new Country();
//provide data of country for setter and add in db and setting countrydropdown Model Object by using below code:
country.setModelObject(addCountry);
param.setCountry(countrylistUpdated);
country.setprovider(new CountryProvider);
target.add(addCountry);
```

page is redirect to home page but I am getting below error

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Exception in rendering component: [DropDownChoice [Component id = qualityDropDown]]
at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2589)
at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1698)
at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2380)
at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2308)
at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1524)
at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1759)
at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1734)
at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1657)


........



//some more logs...
......
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: List of choices is null - Was the supplied 'Choices' model empty?
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.AbstractChoice.getChoices(AbstractChoice.java:233)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.AbstractChoice.onComponentTagBody(AbstractChoice.java:376)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:70)
at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2565)
... 103 more
```

while if i select any country then click on add button and save new country then it shows newly added country in dropdown.

Comment: Any idea about the problem

Comment: list is null does not populate anything

Comment: List is not null. Ihave set list sorry for not mentioned the updating list code

Comment: I have provide set of list.

Comment: Did you check list or set contains any items ? surely list is empty thats's why you are getting the error

Comment: @soorapadman I am using wicket-select2.jar for implementing dropdown not wicket dropdown. so i am using countryprovider class which is calling query method and in this method is calling list of choices but in my case when i am not selecting any data from country dropdown, query method is not calling after save new country while if i select any country from dropdown and then try to add new country then it will call query method of countryprovider. Now I hope my query is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer and need to set selected country instead of setting modelObject after save country in db. see below code:

```
Country addCountry = new Country();
//provide data of country for setter and add in db and setting countrydropdown Model Object by using below code:
country.setSelectedCountry(addCountry);
param.setCountry(countrylistUpdated);
country.setprovider(new CountryProvider);
target.add(addCountry);
```